# no such table: pages_page

Tags: python, django, sqlite, mod-wsgi

I'm getting the error above when setting up my website with apache &mod_wsgi.

I've gone through all of the documentation managed to it half working. Here is the full error:

```
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value: no such table: pages_page
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the DB as before i set the site up with mod_wsgi i could run the site with ./manage.py runserver and it would all work fine.

I have to be carefull what code I post for security perposes.

More than happy to post more information if you tell me you need but i don't really know what to post up as the site itself works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. I was missing the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable from the settings.py file so the apache file was looking for it, but it didn't exist.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: For me it was forgetting to run `migrate`

Answer (score 1):

There *is* something wrong with the DB.

When given a nonexistent file name, SQLite will create a new, empty database; and when given an empty file name, SQLite will create a temporary database.

Check that the database file name is configured correctly, and that it's accessible by the web server.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. It's fairly new to me so sorry for the lack of information. Appreciate your help I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Specifically, if using sqlite, make sure using an absolute path to the database file and not relative. The current working directory under Apache will not be where the settings file is.

Comment: How does the webserver actually find the database? is it through the settings.py file? I've now changed the root to the DB in the settings.py file and i'm now getting an internal server error? Does this mean it's now finding the DB but it's not finding the web templates etc?